# str_getcsv that does not remove the enclosure character

Tags: php, split

I would like split a string with comma-separated values into an array. [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) seems to be a good option, but it removes the enclosure character (`"`) if it is at the beginning and end of a value. I would like to keep the enclosure characters. Consider the string `$str = 'foo,"bar","qwe,rty"'`. `str_getcsv($str)` returns

```
['foo', 'bar', 'qwe,rty']
```

I would like to have

```
['foo', '"bar"', '"qwe,rty"']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to express the value `"bar"` in CSV, then you need to escape the terminator character appropriately to `""bar""` (or perhaps `"\"bar\""`, depending on what CSV dialect you're working with). What you're seeing is the correct behaviour of a CSV parser. `...,"bar",...` in CSV means `..., bar, ...`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. Actually, I'm not working with CSV. I just want to split a string of comma-separated values, and `str_getcsv` seemed like a good solution.

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own parser for this if it's not an existing standardised format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = 'foo,"bar","qwe,rty"'
$res = preg_split('/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/', $str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Thanks. Good try! But, unfortunately, it fails when values contain escaped quotes, such as `"foo,\"bar"`.